# how to use Kmean centers, for testing new data?

Tags: c++, cluster-analysis, k-means, opencv3.0, norm

this is what I'm going to do!  ( maybe this method is wrong in the first place, tell me if I'm wrong)
I have a data set of 300 images, I extract 36 features from each image and create a feature matrix  300*36 , then I use K-mean clustering to  cluster these features

```
kmeans(feature, ClusterNumber , lables,TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER&CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 10000, 0.0001),10,KMEANS_PP_CENTERS ,centers);
```

Now I have my clusters center(which is a ClusterNumber*36 Mat), So what I'm going to do, is for new images(unseen data), I calculate the feature vector and find the distance between that vector and my cluster centers. the new image belongs to the cluster with minimum distance.

I wrote this function to calculate distance :

```
 void calculateDistance( )
    {

        if (features.cols==centers.cols)
        {

            vector<float> resvec;
            for (int i=0;i<centers.rows;i++)
            {
                double res =  norm(features,centers.row(i), cv::NORM_L2SQR );
                resvec.push_back(res);

            }
            int minElementIndex = std::min_element(resvec.begin(),resvec.end()) - resvec.begin();
            cerr<<minElementIndex<<endl;

        }
        else
        {
            cerr<<"vector size mismatch!\n";
        }


    }
```

Surprisingly, for all feature vector(even train data), this function yields the same result! (minElementIndex is always 2)
I even test my theory with some random points (size (500*2)) and it worked like a charm, new data correctly categorized into the right cluster. 
so what's going on when feature vector increase to 36 columns? am I missing something ?!

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not give us enough information as to what is going on. dbeug this function, you will be able to find the error.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher So you mean the theory is correct and there is a bug in this code? 
features is a 1*36 Mat & centers is a 5*36 Mat, I thought if I put all my code here makes it difficult to read   :|

Comment: That's why you need to debug and check what is going on in the loop. From a glance, it seems to be OK, you get the closest center, but I'm not sure what you are passing is correct or not.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher thanks for reply, centers is exactly what Kmean returns, and the feature is the same as the train data, each time a row from train data ... I'm sure the input is correct :|

Comment: As I've said, there is not enough to tell you anything more than "debug the code and check the computations".

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I've been examining the inputs for hours...now I'm 100% sure the feature vector is the same as the one I gave to the k-mean algorithm for training, I'm just using the function to calculate the distance and it's not working

Comment: Debug the distance computation then...